# Power BI Summarize by Unique ID and allow filtering on other dimensions

Tags: powerbi, duplicates, summarize

I have a dataset that has a unique ID for each 'case' but there are multiple rows as each 'case' can be linked to several dimensions. But as there is only one unique ID or case, when summing this with other amounts, in the scenario below, BR_1 needs to be counted only once as £4000. All the solutions I've seen (SUMMARIZE, CALCULATE) works only for a finite scenario but the solution needs to be dynamic so that if someone say selected HR, Alpha, Customer the total amount would be 4500. (And if they selected Sales, Alpha Customer, the total is £4000.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following measure:

```
SUMX(SUMMARIZE(table, table[ID], table[Amount]), table[Amount])
```

This will work with any combination of filters in the different categories and will only count each amount once. The caveat is that either each ID has to have always the same Amount or you need to have only one row per "case" for the same id and force the different filters to always be selected.